# regex match any directory name in CXS

Tags: php, regex

under CXS (ConfigServer eXploit Scanner) I can add directories to ignore during a virus scan on a cpanel server.

my problem is that when a user has more than 1 website in his cpanel account the dir look like this:

/home/username/**domain1.com**/public_html/dir1/dir2
/home/username/**domain2.com**/public_html/dir1/dir2

could you please tell me the correct regex code to include any directory name where /**domain1.com**/ could be any directory name.

I tried /home/username/*/public_html/dir1/dir2 but it's not working.

thanks

Comment: Does this pertain to PHP?

Comment: I thought yes because it's website related sorry if it's not. Can I edit?

Comment: I don't know whether it does or not. I'm trying to determine whether you need a PHP regex, or whether this should be a glob, or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to backslash all the forward slashes and exclude the possibility that a directory has a `/` or a `NULL` (0x00) char in its name:

```
\/home\/username\/[^\/\x00]+\/public_html\/dir1\/dir2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
/home/username/[^/]+/public_html/dir1/dir2
```

Note that character set: [^/] allows the directory name to consist of anything except a forward-slash. 
So you may want to lock that down to a more specific character set, and be less permissive.